# Getting and Setting key-value Properties

Tags: java, properties

I have something like:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // This type of key-value property is in several code lines
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", settings.getSmtpProtocol());
```

In my code, props is accessed at several places. And each time, I need to access some property by its string key. Recently, I made a small code change in one of these key strings, and the key mismatch created a havoc.

What should be the correct design to avoid this kind of problem in my code base, assuming it increases in size and complexity in near future? Following options that I can think of, but not sure what should be the best way:

1. Instead of writing keys as bare strings like "mail.transport.protocol", "mail.smtp.host", "mail.smtp.port" at several places in code, have them stored in a class? And unit test whether appropriate class variable is added into properties or not?
2. Should I refactor props to another class [with only my required properties] alltogether, given props is get/set in many code lines already?
3. Have key strings as it is in props and get the "keys" as unit tested? But, keys are written several times as bare strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate properties file. say mail.properties.

This file holds all key value pairs. In future if somebody wants to change any of the properties, he can just update this properties file instead of changing java classes.

Then create a Java class to load all of these properties and create public static constants for each of the properties in that class.

Use the above constants where ever you want to use them.

Comment: My design actually involves saving the property strings and properties as you said. Thanks, my code looks cleaner now.